# How to pick images from android mobile gallery and show all selected images in listview?

Tags: android

I need some help.Actually i want to choose multiple images from android mobile gallery and want to show all selected images into another gallery or listview and one more action i have to perform that clicking on that listview or gallery image will be send to a auto mail.How can i do this?

Anyone have idea about this.Please let me know.

Comment: Have a look at this post - [Android custom image gallery with checkbox in grid to select multiple](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/)

Comment: This link may also help you.  http://ttlnews.blogspot.in/2011/04/horizontally-sliding-grid-of-images-in.html

Comment: Neetika...have u did any code or not tried yet?